# Manually restarting `ng build --watch` or `ng serve`

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, ng-build

When we use nodemon, for example, we can manually trigger a rebuild by typing `rs` to stdin and hitting return/enter.

I am wondering if there is a way to manually trigger a rebuild when using `ng build --watch` or `ng serve`. On occasion, these fail to pick up files, or fail during a bigger refactor. Instead of using ctrl-c, I am wondering if there is a way to type something into stdin.

Comment: Please explain your Question a little bit more with example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to club them

```
nodemon ng build --watch
```

And it works in both cases, changes as well as `rs` manual restart

[image: Nodemon]

Comment: but I guess you need to configure nodemon to not watch any files, only listen for stdin?

Comment: I suppose nodemon could watch some files that `ng serve` / `ng build` doesn't, and then you could really tag-team. For example, nodemon could watch `.angular-cli.json`, that would be radical.

Comment: In my test it works without a problem, give it a shot

Comment: also note this will not allow for incremental builds, and that's the problem :(

Comment: I was hoping that `rs` would restart an incremental build, not kill the process and start a new one

Comment: Yep, works nice but is very slow compared to simple `ng serve --watch true`. Restarts all the application, thus not suitable for Angular apps.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a space in a .ts file and save it.  Adding a space to a .html file doesnt work